# Using PKCS7_sign to sign a message in FoxPro

Tags: openssl, foxpro

I am trying to use PKCS7_sign from libeay32 in FoxPro, but don´t really know much about encryption.

I have the following:

A string variable with this (public key):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXAIBAAKBgQCai5tzRyUbP32sY/16acr+isSBTW/k/t6DA5lcTKQ3P9r+Wlns
...
na1O9rEZAskh7LeVKVMGxszSFfR91EuQpkw3HT5ynCU=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

A string variable with this (certificate):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Yjs6K/HUQzQQ0fnRhpKYLHY2kOUB5SwNwNEC7isEUBkDNnuh52ZEpSI/fN+4PONN
...
HvCAaD4WhNInP+kwYAKx+5nOHXhL8omgpKgvRGX8
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

A string variable with a message like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<loginTicketRequest version="1.0">
...
</loginTicketRequest>
```

How do I end up with a signed message using PKCS7_sign?

I have tried to follow some code snipets I found, but I keep getting an exception when calling PKCS7_sign.

I have used:

```
BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())
PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey
PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX
BIO_new_mem_buf
```

But really without having much idea or understanding of what or why I am doing. The signature for PKCS7_sign is

```
PKCS7_sign(X509 *signcert, EVP_PKEY *pkey, STACK_OF(X509) *certs, BIO *data, int flags)
```

I think the problem is getting the key and certificate data I have in what I understand is a PEM format, to an X509 an a EVP_PKEY format.

**UPDATE SOME HOURS AND 1000 CUPS OF COFFEE LATER:**

I finally managed to pull this out. Since I am basically shootin in the dark, I don´t know if there are some problems with the code, here is what I have so far, and its working:

```
Lparameters pXml

Declare SSL_library_init In 'ssleay32.dll'

Declare BIO_free In 'libeay32.dll' Integer bio

Declare Integer BIO_s_mem In 'libeay32.dll'

Declare Integer BIO_new In 'libeay32.dll' Integer Type

Declare EVP_PKEY_free In 'libeay32.dll' Integer ikey

Declare X509_free In 'libeay32.dll' Integer a

Declare Integer PKCS7_sign In 'libeay32.dll' Integer signcert, Integer ikey, Integer certs, Integer bio, Integer iflags

Declare Integer PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey In 'libeay32.dll' Integer bio, Integer x, Integer cb, String u

Declare Integer PEM_read_bio_X509 In 'libeay32.dll' Integer bio, Integer x, Integer cb, Integer u

Declare Integer BIO_new_mem_buf In 'libeay32.dll' String buf, Integer ilen

Declare Integer PEM_write_bio_PKCS7 In 'libeay32.dll' Integer bio, Integer x

Declare Integer BIO_read In 'libeay32.dll' Integer bio, String @buf, Integer ilen

SSL_library_init()

m.cbuf = Filetostr(This.UtilGetPath() + This.Cuit + '.crt')
m.kbuf = Filetostr(This.UtilGetPath() + This.Cuit + '.key')

m.bioc = BIO_new_mem_buf(m.cbuf, Len(m.cbuf))

m.fc = PEM_read_bio_X509(m.bioc, 0, 0, 0)

m.biok = BIO_new_mem_buf(m.kbuf, Len(m.kbuf))

m.fk = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(m.biok, 0, 0, 0)

m.biom = BIO_new_mem_buf(m.pXml, Len(pXml))

m.smsg  = PKCS7_sign(m.fc, m.fk, 0, m.biom, PKCS7_NOATTR)

m.bios = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())

PEM_write_bio_PKCS7(m.bios, m.smsg)

m.buf = Space(4096)

m.nlen = BIO_read(bios, @m.buf, Len(m.buf))

m.buf = Left(m.buf, nlen)

BIO_free(m.bios)
BIO_free(m.biok)
BIO_free(m.bioc)
BIO_free(m.biom)
X509_free(m.fc)
EVP_PKEY_free(m.fk)

m.buf = Strextract(m.buf, '-----BEGIN PKCS7-----' + 0h0a, '-----END PKCS7-----')

Return m.buf
```

One of the problems I see (I am shure there are others) is that I am not freeing the result from PKCS7_sign. How do I release m.smsg in this case? I tried BIO_free on it but of course it does not work, there must be some function somewhere for releasing a PKCS7 structure.

Another thing I don´t like is the use of BIO_read, but I was unable to use BIO_get_mem_data.

**UPDATE 2**

I found PKCS7_free and figured out BIO_get_mem_data is a macro for BIO_ctrl, so I now have:

```
m.lnLen = BIO_ctrl(m.bios, BIO_CTRL_INFO, 0, @m.parg)
```

To get the pointer to the data and the length, and also I do at the end a

```
PKCS7_free(m.smsg)
```

Now I think I am done.

Comment: By the way I'am already doing this with capicom, but want to get rid of that dependency.